# How to use classes in other package?

Tags: java

Can I import and use a class from another package? In Eclipse I made 2 packages, one is main other is second

```
main
 -main (class)
second
 -second (class)
```

I want the main function of main class to call the function x in second class. How can I do it? I tried:

```
import second; 
second.x(); (if both classes are in the same package then it works)
second.second.x();
```

None of them worked, and I'm out of ideas now.

Comment: What do you mean by main and second main?  What are the names of the classes and packages they're in?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to provide the full path that you want to import.

```
import com.my.stuff.main.Main;
import com.my.stuff.second.*;
```

So, in your main class, you'd have:

```
package com.my.stuff.main

import com.my.stuff.second.Second;   // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE FOR YOUR QUESTION

class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Second second = new Second();
      second.x();  
   }
}
```

**EDIT: adding example in response to Shawn D's comment**

There is another alternative, as Shawn D points out, where you can specify the full package name of the object that you want to use.  This is very useful in two locations.  First, if you're using the class exactly once:

```
class Main {
    void function() {
        int x = my.package.heirarchy.Foo.aStaticMethod();

        another.package.heirarchy.Baz b = new another.package.heirarchy.Bax();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, this is useful when you want to differentiate between two classes with the same short name:

```
class Main {
    void function() {
        java.util.Date utilDate = ...;
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if you're only referencing the class in one spot, you can just use the full package + classname in code without doing the import, or if you need to resolve the same classname used in two import statements.

Answer (score 5):

Given your example, you need to add the following import in your `main.main` class:

```
import second.second;
```

Some bonus advice, make sure you titlecase your class names as that is a Java standard.  So your example Main class will have the structure:

```
package main;  //lowercase package names
public class Main //titlecase class names
{
    //Main class content
}
```

Comment: You need to make your second class "public"

Answer (score 2):

It should be like `import package_name.Class_Name` --> If you want to import a specific class
(or)

`import package_name.*` --> To import all classes in a package