# How to use classes of a package in another package which is in a project created at a different eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

I find a related question here- [java how to use classes in other package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3480389/1930402)

But, in my case, I want Class A of ProjectA to be used in ClassB of Project B. Project A and Project B are located in different eclipse workspaces or two different folders.

Is this possible, without putting both projects in one folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a nice solution. Use maven dependency!

In Project B's pom.xml, add dependency for Project A.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>GroupId of Project A</groupId> //can be copied from Project A's POM
        <artifactId>Artifact Id of Project A</artifactId> //can be copied from Project A's POM
        <version>Version of Project A</version> //can be copied from Project A's POM
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This worked in my case, since both my projects are Maven projects.

Answer (score 3):

You can import a existing project to your project without copy it into your workspace folder. So ProjectB will be in another folder but you can use it in your workspace.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a jar of Project A and use it in Project B. Then use Class A of Project A in ClassB of project B.

Also you can import project A folder in classpath of Project B to use Class in Class B. Hope this helps.