# How to create a method that can take in multiple classes as input

Tags: java, android, methods

Take for example:

```
public static String[] multipleOfSameSet(String var,int setLength){
    String[] out = new String[setLength];
    for(int i=0; i<setLength; i++){
        out[i] = var;
    }
    return out;
}
```

but I want this to work for int, double and about 10 other classes. 
I tried using a class in place of String and it gave me a world of errors. Here:

Is it even possible?? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: The answer is called [generic types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? You could use the generic class "Object" but there is probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do with this.

Comment: The answer is also known as protocol based development ... make sure your various input types implement the requisite interface.

Comment: `int` and `double` aren't classes.

Comment: @immibis int and double ARE classes. try Integer x = new Integer(5)

Comment: @Laszlowaty Integer is not int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. One option is to try and find a class that is a superclass of all the classes you want to use, or an interface all your classes implement. In your case, the only candidate might be Object:

```
public static Object[] multipleOfSameSet(Object var, int setLength) {
    Object[] out = new Object[setLength];
    for(int i = 0; i < setLength; i++) {
        out[i] = var;
    }
    return out;
}
```

This will work, because all Java classes extend Object, either directly or indirectly. Primitive values get converted into objects automaticaly (ints become `Integer`s, doubles become `Double`s and so on).

The downside of this approach is that, well, you get an array of Objects back, and there's not much you can do with those. What you might want to consider instead is making your method accept some generic type T, and returning an ArrayList of T's:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> multipleOfSameSet(T object, int setLength) {
    ArrayList<T> out = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(int i = 0; i < setLength; i++) {
        out.add(object);
    }
    return out;
}
```

However, if you don't need to modify the list afterwards, I'd go with this:

```
public static <T> List<T> multipleOfSameSet(T object, int setLength) {
    return Collections.nCopies(setLength, object);
}
```

Comment: This is bad solution. It forces you to use `projections`.

Comment: @Laszlowaty it works but why do you say it is bad solution and what are projections?

Comment: It leads to class cast exceptions when you cast your Object to some concrete class that i'snt correct at runtime

Comment: I'm now sure i've used proper word. Projections are changing type of an variable. For example: `double a;double b; int c = (int)a/b;`

Comment: @Laszlowaty Ah, you were thinking about *casts*. I've added a second example that gives you a typed ArrayList.

Comment: Yes, casts. Damn english ;)

Comment: @WanderNauta only problem is my output is totally different. is there no way i can cast it back to int or string if i want to. normal (int) casting donyt seem to be woorking

Comment: @Lasz I've spent a while trying out both the generic (with Arraylist) method and the Object method and i noticed that my output can be read as Objects or Arraylist but then the loss all property of their intended class and i can not cast them with an error or the other. for example in the case of String, i can not use the String.concat() method on it but i can print the String as is. Without the individual class property of the output, my code is quite useless. What do I do?

Comment: @kbluue [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java) It should help ;-)

Comment: I understand how casting work now but it still doesnt work with my code. Is it because mine is an ArraySet?? i include the [] to specify that I am casting to an array and it still doesn't work @Lasz

Comment: @kbluue did you used generic types? Did you pass Class reference to your Array? I don't know java good enough. I think you should create new question for your problem.

Comment: @Las i figured that out but i have a new issue. I'm creating a method and i need a new instance of a Generic Type. I cant seem to understand the solution here as they both seem to require me create a new class and i dont think that is necessary. Please could you expand further. The answers are here ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434041/instantiating-generics-type-in-java ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java ... http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860 (is there a way we could directly chat in here?)

Comment: @kbluue well i have no if there is chat here. My java isn't good, really. I think other people will be more helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can use interfaces or defined class types..

```
public static MyInterface[] multipleOfSameSet(MyInterface var, int setLength) {
    MyInterface[] out = new MyInterface[setLength];
    for(int i = 0; i < setLength; i++) {
        out[i] = var;
    }
    return out;
}
```