# What is the best way to save small java programs in NetBeans as far as doing many exercises?

Tags: java, netbeans, organization

I am planning to do all the exercises from a introduction to java textbook and was wondering how to save each program individually in the IDE NetBeans. Is making a Project for each exercises necessary. I would like to be able to put these problems in order by chapter. Having them in Netbeans would be a great help down the road but if its impossible I was thinking I could always write the program in Netbeans and just save the java and class file in a separate folder.

Thanks for the quick responses I'll be gone for a while to reply to anymore responses.

Comment: You could make main packages like `course.chapter01.exercise02`. It depends whether source code can be downloaded, so the package & project structure is given.

Comment: It's up to you. I would strongly consider looking in to using version control as soon as possible if you're serious about not losing anything.

Comment: You can always have multiple projects folders. For instance for work I do for different companies, the folder of all the projects involved are completely separated per company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a necessity to create a project for each exercise. I'm assuming that your exercises are most likely to be single file programs. In that case, you can just use `shift` + `F6` to run the current open file.

Comment: thanks but i wasn't able to get the shift + F6 to work. Do i have to highlight the code or click on the java file?

Comment: Make sure that the current file opened in the editor has a `public static void main(String[] args){}` function.

Comment: I got it. I was pressing F8, this is deffinityly the fastest way to just have programs written with file names and just run them when needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single project, and add different packages/folders in that project. Then you can use your main class to call some sort of class in each package, to start every exercise.

Comment: thank you I will need to figure out how to call the class from another package but i found information on that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480389/java-how-to-use-classes-in-other-package

Answer (score 0):

When I worked on tens of exercises while completing AP Course, I always created a new project for all of them. I suggest doing so for the following reasons:

- It takes 20s max to create a new project.
- It makes your projects nicely organized.
- You don't need to change the main method every time you want to run an old project.
- It is not very easy to save or load .java file in NetBeans

Comment: The main reason for not wanting to create new project folders is I have some Problems already completed and transferring anything but the java file will be a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Making a netbeans project is required, except if these exercices are quite simple and only exist out of one class. Then you can combine multiple excercises in one project as seperate classes.

If you are learning Object Oriented Programming then you will need multiple classes for one exercise I suppose. Then I can recommend you to use 'Project Groups' to arrange exercises by chapter (each chapter is a seperate Project Group). You can find the project groups menu under the file-tab.